# Theano matrix composed of theano scalars

Tags: python, numpy, theano

How can I create a `theano` matrix composed of `theano` scalars?
The following code creates a `numpy` array composed of `theano` scalars. But I want to have a `theano` matrix instead.

```
C = T.cos
S = T.sin
q = T.fscalar(name="q%d"%self.i)

names = ['x','y','z']
Sx,Sy,Sz = map(lambda name: T.fscalar(name=name),names)

self.mat = np.array([[C(q),-S(q)*C(alpha),S(q)*S(alpha),a*C(q)+Sx],
                    [S(q),C(q)*C(alpha),-C(q)*S(alpha),a*S(q)+Sy],
                    [0,S(alpha),C(alpha),d+Sz],
                    [0,0,0,1]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`theano.tensor.stacklists`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.stacklists) in much the same way as you would use `np.array` to construct a normal numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
from theano import tensor as te

a = te.fscalar("a")
b = te.fscalar("b")
M = te.stacklists([[a, b], [b, a]])

f = theano.function([a, b], M)

print(f(1.0, 2.0))
# [[ 1.  2.]
#  [ 2.  1.]]
```

You could achieve the same result by using [`theano.tensor.stack`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.stack) or [`theano.tensor.concatenate`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.concatenate) to construct a 1D vector from your scalars, then using its `reshape` method to reshape it into a matrix/tensor with your desired dimensions.